# Построить график столбца DataFrame в зависимости от даты (столбец того же DF)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Не могу построить отображение на графике 3-го столбца из файла csv в зависимости от столбца `Date`.

Пример данных (с наименованием столбцов) в CSV файле:

```
Date,1,2,3,4,A,B
2010-01-04,213.429998,214.499996,212.38000099999996,214.009998,123432400,27.727039
```

Date - первый столбец с датами, `a['3'].plot()` - отобразить 3й столбец с (он так и подписан, как "3") - не получается.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
a = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/II/Downloads/222.csv',
                sep=',', encoding='latin1',
                parse_dates=['Date'], dayfirst=True,
                index_col='Date')
a['3'].plot()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот вариант визуализации в Pandas:

Данные:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as wb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = wb.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', '2017-01-01')

# симулируем ваш DF
a = a.reset_index()
a.columns = ['Date', '1','2','3','4','A','B']
print(a.head())
```

Вывод:

```
        Date           1           2           3           4        A           B
0 2017-01-03  778.809998  789.630005  775.799988  786.140015  1643100  786.140015
1 2017-01-04  788.359985  791.340027  783.159973  786.900024  1065400  786.900024
2 2017-01-05  786.080017  794.479980  785.020020  794.020020  1315400  794.020020
3 2017-01-06  795.260010  807.900024  792.203979  806.150024  1620500  806.150024
4 2017-01-09  806.400024  809.966003  802.830017  806.650024  1272400  806.650024
```

Визуализация

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

a.set_index('Date')['3'].plot()
```

или:

```
a.plot(x='Date', y='3')
plt.show()
```

Результат будет одинаковым:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

код рабочий. сначала надо отделить даты в отдельный массив и преобразовать несколько, затем по каждому столбцу можно построить график

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

dates = ['01/02/2017','02/02/2017','03/02/2017','04/02/2017','05/02/2017']
x = [dt.datetime.strptime(d,'%d/%m/%Y').date() for d in dates]
data = np.array([[1,2],[2,5],[3,1],[4,0],[5,5]])

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.set_title("Plot title...")    
ax1.set_xlabel('your x label..')
ax1.set_ylabel('your y label...')

ax1.plot(x,data[:,0], c='r', label='data 1')
ax1.plot(x,data[:,1], c='r', label='data 2')
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

leg = ax1.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: матчасть по figure - http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html
Даже в Excel график построить это не одно действие - нужно оси описать, метки осей и данные определить... вот тут всё это и делается, я не знаю чего там много или мало

Comment: я не знаю какая у вас проблема :-) a ['3'].plot() не может работать вообще никогда. 
Это как сказать курьеру "иди"... куда, зачем...

Comment: @EugeneBartosh, `a['3'].plot()` - это нормальная практика для визуализации Pandas.DataFrame. К сожалению автор вопроса забыл пометить вопрос с `pandas` тег.

Comment: ах, ну сорри, панды не знаю ))

Comment: спасибо, а всё потому что панду прогнали, 3 года тому назад, было дело )) вот я её и не повстречал )) но теперь вот знаю где живёт и зайду тоже как-нить

Comment: @EugeneBartosh, :-D